# JavaScript conditional logic for generating object, beginners stuck in the process

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, conditional-statements

**Goal: To create a conditional statement that generates data in a predefined layout for the system.**

example: if  new item is selected, it should include its "id" and set "enable" to true.

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "length": 1,
  "server": "argp",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 4343,
      "enable": true
    }

  ]
}
```

example: if two new items are selected, and one existing item is deselected, the data should look like this:

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "length": 3,
  "server": "argp",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 4343,
      "enable": true
    },
    {
      "id": 5555,
      "enable": true
    },
    {
      "id": 6666,
      "enable": false
    }
  ]
}
```

---

I've written a conditional statement that lists all the selected "id" with "enable: true".

- Figure 1 (Assuming there were initially two items selected):
  [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf80y.png)
- Figure 2 (After selecting the third item, it is also listed):[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqiwp.png)

Here's the code with the conditional statement that is not achieving the desired effect yet:

```
<script>
  var old_data = []; // Define a variable to store previously selected data

  function modalTable() {
    console.log("TABLE MODAL");
    const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    var new_edit_data = {
      draw: 1,
      length: 0,
      server: "argp",
      data: []
    };

    var tablefor4 = $("#example_04").DataTable({
      ajax: {
        url: "http://192.168.03.30:6000/api/message/all", // Fake API
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
        },
        dataSrc: function (response) {
          console.log("DATA MODAL TABLE", response.data);
          return response.data;
        },
      },
      destroy: true,
      columns: [
        { data: "sf", title: "sf" },
        { data: "code", title: "code" },
        { data: "subcode", title: "subcode" },
        { data: "msgtext", title: "msgtext" }, 
        { data: "description", title: "description" },    
        {
          data: null,
          title: "Alarm/Event Setting",
          render: function (data, type, row) {
            var switchId = 'customSwitch_' + row.id; // Assuming you have an 'id' field in your data
            var switchHTML = '<div class="custom-control custom-switch">';
            var isChecked = row.argp ? 'checked' : ''; // Check if rowData.argp is true and add the checked attribute if so
            switchHTML += '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="' + switchId + '" ' + isChecked + '>';
            switchHTML += '<label class="custom-control-label" for="' + switchId + '">Selected</label>';
            switchHTML += '</div>';
            return switchHTML;
          },
          createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
          var switchId = 'customSwitch_' + rowData.id; // Assuming you have an 'id' field in your data
          var switchElement = $(td).find('#' + switchId);
          var previousArgpValue = rowData.argp; // Store the previous argp value
          switchElement.change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              rowData.argp = true;
            } else {
              rowData.argp = false;
            }
            var selectedRows = tablefor4.rows({ selected: true }).data();
            var newSelectedData = selectedRows.filter(function(row) {
              return row.argp === true && !old_data.some(function(prevRow) {
                return prevRow.id === row.id;
              });
            }).map(function(row) {
              return { id: row.id, enable: true };
            });
            old_data = selectedRows.toArray(); // Update previously selected data
            new_edit_data.data = new_edit_data.data.concat(newSelectedData); // Combine newly selected data
            new_edit_data.length = new_edit_data.data.filter(function(row) {
              return row.enable === true;
            }).length;

            // If previously selected data was modified in the new selection, revert the argp value
            if (!old_data.some(function(prevRow) {
              return prevRow.id === rowData.id && prevRow.enable === previousArgpValue;
            })) {
              rowData.argp = previousArgpValue;
            }

            console.log("Selected Rows (new):", new_edit_data);
            console.log("old_data:", old_data);
          });
        }


        },
      ]
    });

    tablefor4.draw();
  }
</script>
```

The current output will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F9ap.png), listing all the selected "id" with "enable: true" (including both old and newly selected ones, but not the newly deselected ones):

**I hope it calculates the number of modifications in the "length" and the newly modified "id" with their corresponding "enable" status.**

For example:

Suppose we select two new items and deselect one old item, the result should be as follows:

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "length": 3,
  "server": "argp",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 4343,
      "enable": true
    },
    {
      "id": 5555,
      "enable": true
    },
    {
      "id": 6666,
      "enable": false
    }
  ]
}
```

For writing wizards, it might be quick, but I'm stuck on this and a bit puzzled. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag. This question seems to deal with JavaScript objects, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I find out myself, but thanks for all the viewers

```
<script>
  function modalTable() {
    console.log("TABLE MODAL");
    const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    var apple = { // Create an object to store data
      draw: 1,
      length: 0, // Initialize to 0
      server: "argp",
      data: []
    };

    var getData; // Define getData in the outer scope

    var tablefor4 = $("#example_04").DataTable({
      ajax: {
        url: "http://192.168.03.30:8000/api/ipc/all", // fake api
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
        },
        dataSrc: function (response) {
          console.log("DATA MODAL TABLE", response.data);
          getData = response.data.map(obj => {
            let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
            result['isChanged'] = false // Assign the variable
            return result
          })

          console.log('DATA CHANGe', getData)

          return getData;
        },
      },
      destroy: true,
      columns: [
        { data: "sf", title: "sf" },
        { data: "code", title: "code" },
        { data: "subcode", title: "subcode" },
        { data: "msgtext", title: "msgtext" },
        { data: "description", title: "description" },
        {
          data: null,
          title: "Alarm/Event Setting",
          render: function (data, type, row) {
            var switchId = 'customSwitch_' + row.id; // Assuming you have an 'id' field in your data
            var switchHTML = '<div class="custom-control custom-switch">';
            var isChecked = row.argp ? 'checked' : ''; // Check if rowData.argp is true, then add checked attribute
            switchHTML += '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="' + switchId + '" ' + isChecked + '>';
            switchHTML += '<label class="custom-control-label" for="' + switchId + '">Selected</label>';
            switchHTML += '</div>';
            return switchHTML;
          },
          createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            var switchId = 'customSwitch_' + rowData.id; // Assuming you have an 'id' field in your data
            var switchElement = $(td).find('#' + switchId);
            switchElement.change(function () {
              if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                rowData.argp = true;
                rowData.isChanged = true; // Update isChanged to true when "Selected" is checked
                // Find data where isChanged is true
                var changedData = getData.filter(item => item.isChanged === true);
                console.log("Changed Data:", changedData);
              } else {
                rowData.argp = false;
              }
              var selectedRows = tablefor4.rows({ selected: true }).data();
              apple.data = selectedRows.filter(function (row) { // Keep only newly selected data
                return row.argp === true;
              }).map(function (row) {
                return { id: row.id, enable: row.argp };
              });
              apple.length = apple.data.length; // Update length
              console.log("Selected Rows:", apple);
              var changedData = getData.filter(item => item.isChanged === true);
              console.log("Changed Data:", changedData);

              const result = transformData(changedData);
              console.log("changedData_to_jsonAPI", result);

              tablefor4.draw();
            });
          }
        },
      ]
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).